Azure SQL Server Database Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 1 HELP
I recently changed the IP for my database and since the I've received this Error **

"Azure SQL Server Database Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 1"

**
Saw a few solutions where creating an SQL login and switching off Windows Authentication to SQL Authentication, but I was unable to find where I could create the login without being signed in, in the first place. Any Suggestions are welcome.

Please show the full message (including the State) value from the SQL Error log, which includes more information. Please show your full connection string.
